# Session limit for OpenSSH server on Ubuntu Desktop 7.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, iptables, openssh

I need restrict session limit on my OpenSSH server only for one session (one connection). I use Ubuntu Desktop 7.10. Of course Version is old, but I need it for experimental purposes. I tried modify my config file - /etc/ssh/sshd_config two ways:

First I changed:

```
MaxStartups 1
```

but it does not work correctly. I can make many connections still.

Second I changed:

```
MaxSessions 1
```

after restart I get error message:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 71: Bad configuration option: MaxSessions
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

I saw to [sshd_config MaxSessions parameter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26170/sshd-config-maxsessions-parameter) and I tried add:

```
mato - maxlogins 1
```

to /etc/security/limits.conf

but it does not work.

I used - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/ too:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 -j REJECT,
```

but I get error message:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.1

The `MaxSessions` option was implemented on the version 5.1 of OpenSSH. Ubuntu 7.10 uses the version 4.6 so, this option will not be available to you. http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-612-2/

Possible solutions:

- Download a newer version of OpenSSH and comple it
- Make a "apt-pinning" and install a newer version of it

What about if you put the following option on your limits.conf?

```
user hard    maxlogins       1
```

Since your ar using a pretty old piece of software, a lot of OpenSSH options and iptables modules could not be available to help you on this task

Comment: Thanks. I tried install newer version, but it is story without end because it depends on the a lot of packages that do not compatibile and etc... I tried add user hard maxlogins 1 too, but it does not help me. I don´t understand because it does not restrict number of logins... I am going try apt-pinning...

Comment: I tried http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html, but it does not work in my case. :-(

Comment: In this case, your pam + ssh solution could be bugged too. Reference: https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/pam-developers/2012-June/000280.html - https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/pam-developers/2012-June/000281.html - The second option is that your SSH need a fine tunning to work correctly with pam(ex: http://tech.kaotix.dk/?p=89). Needless to say that the version your are using could have limitations due to the old verson ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have used http://tech.kaotix.dk/?p=89. For user mato it works correctly (it allow only one SSH session), but for user root - I can connect with many sessions still. My limits.conf - http://pastebin.com/2ZCSjzZ9. Can you help me please with user root too?

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: Maybe it could be a bug, or it is not implemented to limit the root login, like this one: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=597225. I´m researching a little more before posting a decent answer ;)

Comment: thanks but now Do I have any solution for my case?

Comment: Since i could not figure out what is causing root to be allowed to make as many connections as he wants, i will suggest you to disable root login on SSH(`vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `PermitRootLogin no`) as a workaround so you will have one extra layer of security. What do you think? :)

Comment: ok :-) This system will work as honeypot. I have done your recommendations and I will wait for final result. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :)