# How to Set MaxSessions parmeter in sshd_config

Tags: linux, ssh, configuration, sshd, session

When I set MaxSessions flag to 1, I can have multiple sessions via ssh connection and set it to 2 or more has no effect as well then.

If i set MaxSessions flag as 1, there should be allow only one ssh connection.

Maybe you can direct me to right solution.

Comment: the MaxSessions parameter is meant to limit the number of multiplexed ssh sessions you can have over a single ssh session.  i think this is what you need. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26170/sshd-config-maxsessions-parameter#answer-28085

Answer (score 1):

Se ven is right,
The MaxSessions parameter is meant to limit the number of multiplexed ssh sessions you can have over a single ssh session

You can set the maximum number of unauthenticated connections to sshd with MaxStartups (see sshd_config(5)) but that won't affect the number of authenticated connections.

You could, however, restrict the number of overall connections to sshd with a packet filter like Netfilter (iptables) using the connlimit extension.

Example (slightly modified directly from iptables(8)):

```
# limit the number of parallel SSH requests to 16 per class C sized network (24 bit netmask)
iptables -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 16 --connlimit-mask 24 -j REJECT
```